# How to free member (i.e BSTR, SAFEARRAY, VARIANT) of an IDL User Defined Structure which is encapsulated in a VARIANT?

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc, atl, com+

I have a structure defined in IDL. This structure has following members:

```
{
    BSTR m_sFirst;
    BSTR m_sSecond;
    VARIANT m_vChildStruct; //This member encapsulate a sub structure 
    SAFEARRAY __RPC_FAR * m_saArray;
}CustomINFO;
```

I am allocating the memory for the structs using CoTaskMemAlloc and encapsulating it in Variant as follows:

```
vV->vt = VT_RECORD;
vV->pvRecord = pStruct; //Pointer of sturct
vV->pRecInfo = pRI; //RecordInfo Interface
```

Is it enough to call VariantClear to deallocate the memory of struct and its members?
Will it also release the IRecordInfo interface?

Or i have to manually get the encapsulated struct and deallocate each member myself and then use CoTaskMemFree to deallocate sturct.

Thanks

Picaro De Vosio

Comment: You already need an IRecordInfo for the "main" structure.  Why not just declare the child structure as-is instead of using a variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VariantClear` will call `IRecordInfo::Clear`, which releases the memory held by members of the struct, but supposedly doesn't release the struct itself (that's why you can't correctly return a struct in an  `[out] VARIANT`). the IRecordInfo should be released, too.

("should" means "otherwise, a lot of existing code would break/be broken").

Some more info here: http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/4.htm